# DBSCAN in scikit-learn of Python: Trouble understanding result of DBSCAN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

This example is from Data Science for dummies:

```
digits = load_digits()
X = digits.data
ground_truth = digits.target

pca = PCA(n_components=40)
Cx = pca.fit_transform(scale(X))

DB = DBSCAN(eps=4.35, min_samples=25, random_state=1)
DB.fit(Cx)



for k,cl in enumerate(np.unique(DB.labels_)):
    if cl >= 0:
        example = np.min(np.where(DB.labels_==cl)) # question 1
        plt.subplot(2, 3, k)
            plt.imshow(digits.images[example],cmap='binary', # question 2
            interpolation='none') 
        plt.title('cl '+str(cl))
plt.show()
```

My  questions are:

1. np.where(DB.labels_==cl) I don't understand on which array we apply np.where
   when I print np.where(DB.labels_==cl) it is looks like it applied to DB.core_sample_indices_. But I don't understand why. As I could understand from documentation for np.where, np.where(DB.labels_==cl) should be applied on DB.labels_.
2. How come np.min(np.where(DB.labels_==cl)) gives me indice which in digits.images plots me correct image.
   Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The output of the operation `DB.labels_ == cl` is an array of Boolean such that `(DB.labels_ == cl)[i]` is `True` if `DB.labels_[i] == cl`.

   Thus `np.where` is applied to the array `DB.labels_ == cl`. And its ouput, if used on a single array, are the nonzero elements of this array, *i.e.* the element which are `True`.

   The operation `np.where(DB.labels_ == cl)` returns the indices of the elements of `DB.labels_` that are equals to `cl`. These are the element of the data used in `fit` that have been labeled by `DB` as part of the cluster `cl`.
2. In this case `np.min` returns the smallest indice in the previous array. This means that it will retrieve the first element of your set that have been classified as being part of the cluster `cl`. By looping thru all the clusters, you retrieve a set of examples of the images that constitute in your clusters.

   This indices correspond to the one in data.image as `DB.labels_` contains the labels of each of the point in the dataset that you feeded to `DB.fit`. This dataset as the same order as `data.images`.